# Best practice on organizing EF configuration classes in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm starting with a new project and am using EF core with fluent API.

Currently I have some few configuration classes for a simple data model. Over time it will grow, there will be more and more. 
Some with changes on the existing data model, some with new features or even deletions.

- What is a good practice to organize those configuration classes?
- Having them separated in folders as for development sprints?
- Writing a prefix to the class name (eg _1PersonConfig.cs)?

Comment: `_1PersonConfig` this would be particularly ugly

Comment: I completely agree. I'm just thinking on how the overview will not be lacking when there are hundreds of files. Subfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself place the configurations inside the .cs file as my models file.
And their naming convention would be same as the model plus "Configuration" e.g. `User` and `UserConfiguration`.
As you are using fluent API, the configuration classes implement I think `IEntityTypeConfiguration<>` So you can easily register all configurations **Generically** in `OnModelCreating` in you Context class.(using reflection, I can shre some peice of code if you want)

In this case you never mind registration as a new model is added and for modifying there is no way but open your main model's file and change it without pain of losing in folders looking for config file.

Comment: Do you mean everything according to a type like `IEntityTypeConfiguration<Person>` will be in the same file. Also changes and enhancements? By thinking about that, it makes sense to me.

Comment: I think I got the idea. I was thinking in terms of migration files, that configuration classes also represent something like a migration history which seems to be completely wrong as the source control is managing that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not keen on the reflection idea. The performance argument isn't the main issue here (since you only create the model once per runtime - which may still be undesirable in a web context), but rather that it renders you unable to have more than one dbcontext with its own entities as each context would create a model for all the configurations it can find.

Comment: If you have more than one context you can have some base classes or interfaces to specify your configurations for appropriate context then use them in context.

Comment: And also it wouldn't be runtime at all. Cause you should just register then in startup.